# I can not understand this job task

Tags: job-scheduler

I received this excel sheet containing three sheets [form, tree, workflow]. It was a php developer task. I can not understand what I have to do. And what the expected result of that. And are form, tree and workflow some architecture that I should search for to understand the task?

Thanks

[image: form]

[image: tree]

[image: workflow]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. Please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits.